# rspec for testing json results

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, rspec

So I am basically trying to write rspec to test my json results:

```
 patient_allergies = patient.patient_allergies
  expect(response_body['allergies'].size).to eq(patient_allergies.size)

  patient_allergies.each_with_index do |allergy, index|
    expect(response_body['allergies'][index]['name']).to eq(allergy.name)
    allergy.patient_allergy_reactions.each_with_index do |reaction, index|
      expect(response_body['reactions'][index]['name']).to eq(reaction.name)
    end
  end
```

My tables above are patient_allergies and patient_allergy_reactions.

The above tests work fine. But the problem is I am comparing by index.

If the order of the json changes, the test would fail. Is there a better way to write tests for this?
my json looks like this:

```
"allergies": [
{
"name": "Allergy1",
"reactions": [
]
},
{
"name": "Allergy2",
"reactions": [
{
"name": "Reaction1",
"severity": "Medium"
}
]
}
],
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `detect` and the [`include`](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/2-0/docs/matchers/include-matcher) matcher to help you out here:

```
patient_allergies = patient.patient_allergies
response_allergies = response['allergies'] || []

expect(response_allergies.size).to eq(patient_allergies.size)
patient_allergies.each |allergy| do
  response_allergy = response_allergies.detect{|a| a['name'] == allergy.name}
  expect(response_allergy).to_not be_nil
  patient_reactions = allergy.patient_allergy_reactions
  response_reactions = (response_allergy['reactions'] || []).map{|r| r['name']}
  expect(response_reactions.size).to eq(patient_reactions.size)
  expect(response_reactions).to include(*patient_reactions.map(&:name))
end
```

Comment: Thanks. The reaction name can be nil. is that why I am getting this error?   Failure/Error: response_reaction_names = response_body['reactions'].map{|a| a['name']}
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `map' for nil:NilClass

Comment: the corresponding patient_allergy_reaction would not exist in the database. there would be only patient_allergy in some cases. I have printed the json in my code above

Comment: the json can alsom return empty allergy.Failure/Error: response_allergy = response_allergies.detect{|a| a['name'] == allergy.name}
     NoMethodError:
       undefined method `detect' for nil:NilClass

Comment: For example, for a patient with no allergies would return allergies:[]

Comment: Failure/Error: expect(response_reactions).to include(allergy_reactions.map(&:name))
       expected [] to include []

Comment: @Micheal: updated to be nil-safe and splat the patient reaction names array